# Android Animation Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Hi every one I have got basic problem,I have got 2 animate-set (left_to_right and right_to_left) I want when i click which button start that animate(I have got 1 imageview)

**My problem is views animation not change**

my code is here:

```
resim=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_sayfa); 
sol=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.soltosag);     
sag=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.sagtosol);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sol);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sag);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                resim.setAnimation(null);

                resim.startAnimation(sol);

            }       

        }); 

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

                    resim.startAnimation(sol);



                }   

            }
        });
```

anim/right_to_left:sag.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:duration="1250" 
        android:fillAfter="true"
        />
        <alpha 
             android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="1250"

            />
     </set>
```

anim/left_to_right:sol.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="1250" 


    />
    <alpha 

         android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0"
    android:duration="1250"

        />
 </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but I'll try to help you.

What is "button" ? Shouldn't be b2 instead ?

And you are using twice the animation "sol".

```
resim.startAnimation(sol);
```

Maybe

```
resim.startAnimation(sag);
```

Can you explain better what you're trying to do ?

Comment: thanks for answer i've got 2 button (b1 and button) if user click b1 ı want to imageview right to left transation if click another button ı wantto imageview transation left to right I hope ı can explained my question thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you need to use "%p". I mean "100%p" instead of "100%".

Documentation says :

> the optional %p suffix provides a size relative to some parent container

If your imageView layout_gravity is set to right, you can do like this :

soltosag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="1250" />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0"
    android:duration="1250" />
```

sagtosol.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="1250" />

<alpha 
     android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1250" />
```

yourActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button b1;
private Button button;

private ImageView resim;

private Animation sol;
private Animation sag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    resim = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.resim);

    sol = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.animator.soltosag);     
    sag = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.animator.sagtosol);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resim.startAnimation(sol);
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resim.startAnimation(sag);
        }
    });

    }

}
```

EDIT :

layout/main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/resim"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="b1"/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I cant solved my problem my real problem my animation not changed for example if I click button (b) animation normal run (sol.xml animation) but i click another button my animation not change.So first clicked buttons animation going on not changed another animation

Comment: yes ı tried it and animation direction not changed always fixed –